# ROR + Search Domain Name From Table Using Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby I have to write a method, in which i have to retrieve the id from table of those employee having email id of domain `"stackoverflow.com"` and `other than this email domain`.

Separate Method should be there for this...

Table name : people, attribute name :email. Please suggest the method ?

Answer (score 1):

People.find(:all, :select => 'id', :conditions => ["email like ?", '%stackoverflow.com'])